# Remote Computer File Transfer PowerShell script does not do logging correctly

Tags: powershell, logging

**This is my remote computer file transfer PowerShell script:**

#--------------------------------------------------------[Initialisations]-------------------------------------------------------

```
#Clears the contents of the DNS client cache
Clear-DnsClientCache

#Loading script configuration
$configuration = Get-Content '.\Resources\Remote Computer File Transfer Configuration.cfg' | Select-Object | ConvertFrom-StringData

#Initializing report file
New-Item -Path $configuration.ReportFile -ItemType File

$fileList = Get-Content -Path $configuration.FileList
$computerList = Get-Content -Path $configuration.ComputerList

#Initializing file counters
$successfulTransfers = 0
$failedTransfers = 0
```

#---------------------------------------------------------[Functions]----------------------------------------------------------

```
function Write-Log
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $false)]
        [String]
        $OperationSuccessful,

        [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = $false)]
        [String]
        $Message,

        [Parameter(Position = 2, Mandatory = $false)]
        [String]
        $LogSeparator
    )
    if($null -eq $LogSeparator)
    {
        $timestamp = Get-Date -Format "yyyy.MM.dd. HH:mm:ss:fff"
        $logEntry = $timestamp + " - " + $Message
    }
    else
    {
            $logEntry = $LogSeparator
    }

    
    if($OperationSuccessful -eq "Successful")
    {
            Write-Host $logEntry -ForegroundColor Green -BackgroundColor Black
    }
    elseif($OperationSuccessful -eq "Failed")
    {
            Write-Host $logEntry -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Black
    }
    elseif($OperationSuccessful -eq "Partial")
    {
            Write-Host $logEntry -ForegroundColor Blue -BackgroundColor Black
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host $logEntry -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Black
    }
    
        Add-content -Path $configuration.LogFile -Value $logEntry
    
        Add-content -Path $configuration.ReportFile -Value $logEntry
}

function Send-Report
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]
        $FinalMessage
    )

    if($configuration.SendReport -eq "true")
    {
        $body = $configuration.Body + "`n" + $FinalMessage

        Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $configuration.SmtpServer `
                         -Port $configuration.Port `
                         -To $configuration.To `
                         -From $configuration.From `
                         -Subject $configuration.Subject `
                         -Body $body `
                         -Attachments $configuration.ReportFile
                         
        Remove-Item -Path $configuration.ReportFile
    }
}
```

#---------------------------------------------------------[Execution]----------------------------------------------------------

```
Write-Log -LogSeparator $configuration.LogTitle
Write-Log -LogSeparator $configuration.LogSeparator

#Get credential from user input
$credential = Get-Credential

$message = "User " + $credential.UserName + " entered credentials"
Write-Log -Message $message

foreach($file in $fileList)
{
    if((Test-Path -Path $file) -eq $true)
    {
        $message = "Successfully checked " + $file + " file - ready for transfer."
        Write-Log -OperationSuccessful "Successful" -Message $message
    }
    else
    {
        $message = "Failed to access " + $file + " file. It does not exist."
        Write-Log -OperationSuccessful "Failed" -Message $message
        $message = "Script stopped - MISSING FILE ERROR"
        Write-Log -OperationSuccessful "Failed" -Message $message
        Write-Log -Message $configuration.LogSeparator
        Send-Report -FinalMessage $message
        Exit
    }
}
$message = "Successfully accessed all files - ready for transfer"
Write-Log -OperationSuccessful "Successful" -Message $message

#Start file transfer
Write-Log -Message "Started file transfer"
foreach($computer in $computerList)
{
    #Mapping network drive
    if((Test-Connection -TargetName $computer -Quiet -Count 1) -eq $true)
    {
        $message = "Successfully accessed " + $computer + " remote computer"
        Write-Log -OperationSuccessful "Successful"-Message $message

        #Network path creation to D partition on the remote computer
        $partition = "\D$"
        $networkPath = "\\" + $computer + $partition

        #Try to create network drive to D partition on the remote computer
        if(New-PSDrive -Name "T" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root $networkPath -Credential $credential)
        {
            $message = "Successfully mapped network drive to D partition on the " + $computer + " remote computer"
            Write-Log -OperationSuccessful "Successful" -Message $message
            $driveMappingSuccessful = $true
        }
        else
        {
            $message = "Failed to map network drive to D partition on the " + $computer + " remote computer"
            Write-Log -OperationSuccessful "Failed" -Message $message

            #Network path creation to C partition on the remote computer
            $partition = "\C$"
            $networkPath = "\\" + $computer + $partition
            
            #Try to create network drive to C partition on the remote computer
            if(New-PSDrive -Name "T" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root $networkPath -Credential $credential)
            {
                $message = "Successfully mapped network drive to C partition on the " + $computer + " remote computer"
                Write-Log -OperationSuccessful "Successful" -Message $message
                $driveMappingSuccessful = $true
            }
            else
            {
                $message = "Failed to map network drive to C partition on the " + $computer + " remote computer - Credential not valid"
                Write-Log -OperationSuccessful "Failed" -Message $message
                $driveMappingSuccessful = $false
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $message = "Failed to access " + $computer + " remote computer - OFFLINE"
        Write-Log -OperationSuccessful "Failed" -Message $message
        $driveMappingSuccessful = $false
    }

    if($driveMappingSuccessful)
    {
        $path = "T:\" + $configuration.TransferFolder

        if((Test-Path $path) -eq $true)
        {
            $message = "Successfully accessed " + $path + " folder"
            Write-Log -OperationSuccessful "Successful" -Message $message
            $deployingFolderSuccessful = $true
        }
        else
        {
            $message = "Failed to access " + $path + " folder - MISSING FOLDER ERROR"
            Write-Log -OperationSuccessful "Failed" -Message $message

            try
            {
                New-Item -Path $path -ItemType "Directory"
            }
            catch
            {
                Write-Log -OperationSuccessful "Failed" -LogSeparator $_.Exception
            }

            if((Test-Path $path) -eq $true)
            {
                $message = "Successfully created " + $path + " folder"
                Write-Log -OperationSuccessful "Successful" -Message $message
                $deployingFolderSuccessful = $true
            }
            else
            {
                $message = "Failed to create " + $path + " folder"
                Write-Log -OperationSuccessful "Failed" -Message $message
                $deployingFolderSuccessful = $false
            }
        }

        if($deployingFolderSuccessful)
        {
            $fileList = Get-Content -Path $configuration.FileList

            foreach($file in $fileList)
            {
                #File name extraction from file full path
                $fileName = Split-Path $file -leaf
        
                try
                {
                    Copy-Item -Path $file -Destination $path -Force
                }
                catch
                {
                    Write-Log -OperationSuccessful "Failed" -LogSeparator $_.Exception
                }

                $transferDestination = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath $file

                if(Test-Path -Path $transferDestination)
                {
                    $message = "Successfully transferred " + $fileName + " file to " + $transferDestination + " folder"
                    Write-Log -OperationSuccessful "Successful" -Message $message
                    $successfulTransfers ++
                }
                else
                {
                    $message = "Failed to transfer " + $fileName + " file to " + $path + " folder"
                    Write-Log -OperationSuccessful "Failed" -Message $message
                    $failedTransfers ++
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $message = "Canceld file transfer to " + $computer + " remote computer"
            Write-Log -OperationSuccessful "Failed" -Message $message
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $message = "Canceld file transfer to " + $computer + " remote computer"
        Write-Log -OperationSuccessful "Failed" -Message $message
    }

    #Network drive removal
    if($driveMappingSuccessful)
    {
        Remove-PSDrive -Name "T"
    }
}

$message = "Completed Remote Computer File Transfer PowerShell Script"
Write-Log -Message $message

if($successfulTransfers -gt 0)
{
    $message = "Successfully transferred " + $successfulTransfers + " files to " + $Destination + " folder"
    Write-Log -OperationSuccessful "Successful" -Message $message
}

if($failedTransfers -gt 0)
{
    $message = "Failed to transfer " + $failedTransfers + " files to " + $Destination + " folder"
    Write-Log -OperationSuccessful "Failed" -Message $message
}

if(($successfulTransfers -gt 0 ) -and ($failedTransfers -eq 0))
{
    $message = "Successfully transferred all files to " + $Destination + " folder"
    Write-Log -OperationSuccessful "Successful" -Message $message
}
elseif(($successfulTransfers -gt 0 ) -and ($failedTransfers -gt 0))
{
    $message = "Successfully transferred some files to " + $Destination + " folder with some failed"
    Write-Log -OperationSuccessful "Partial" -Message $message
}
elseif(($successfulTransfers -eq 0 ) -and ($failedTransfers -gt 0))
{
    $message = "Failed to transfer any file to " + $Destination + " folder"
    Write-Log -OperationSuccessful "Failed" -Message $message
}

Write-Log -Message $configuration.LogSeparator

#Sends email with detailed report and deletes temporary report log file
Send-Report -FinalMessage $message
```

This is .cfg file:

```
LogTitle = ***********************************************  Remote Computer File Transfer PowerShell Script Log  ************************************************
LogSeparator = ******************************************************************************************************************************************************

SendReport = true

LogFile = .\\Resources\\Remote Computer File Transfer Log.log
ReportFile = .\\Resources\\Report.log
FileList = .\\Resources\\File-Paths.txt
ComputerList = .\\Resources\\Computer-List.txt
TransferFolder = _INSTALL

SmtpServer = smtp.mail.com
Port = 25
To = sistem.administrators@company.com
From = powershell@company.com
Subject = Remote Computer File Transfer Report
Body = This is an automated message sent from PowerShell script. Remote Computer File Transfer PowerShell Script has finished executing.
```

**Something is wrong with logging. It must be a problem with Write-Log function. The script actually does the job but nothing is written on the console by Write-Log function, and it just writes this in the picture and I can't figure out why.**

[image]

**Grateful in advance!**

Comment: PLEASE could you edit the question and remove all `<# .SYNOPSIS` stuff.

Comment: Please reformat the question so that it correctly formats code as code. Also, reduce the amount of code down into a [mcve], don't post your whole script.

Comment: Change `if($null -eq $LogSeparator)` into `if(!$LogSeparator)` or `if([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($LogSeparator))`. Since you declared this parameter as string, if unused, the value will be an empty string, not `$null`.

Comment: Well this [$configuration = Get-Content 'D:\Temp\Remote Computer File Transfer Configuration.cfg' | Select-Object | ConvertFrom-StringData] is not providing you what you think it is. This read does not allow you to do the dotted notation you are using. If you just ran that section and then try dot the variable/values, you'll see what is being returned. [$configuration.LogFile 
The property 'LogFile' cannot be found on this object.]

Comment: @postanote It works for me (tested locally), although I would use the `Raw` switch and leave out the `| Select-Object` which has no reason to be there. Of course in the `Execution` part of the code, there is nothing to actually **get** the files listed in the `$configuration.FileList`, but that's a different question..

Comment: @Theo, yeppers, I did the same thing with taking out the Select and should have made that point. Yet as posted by the OP, I was just trying to hint, that line needs to be refactored. Actually I refactored the whole script but decided it was probably less prudent to post vs just the point I was trying to make. As teh rest of the refactor was style, consistency, and fixing those if/then with switch statements, long code lines with and graveyard marks, splatting, etc.

Comment: @postanote Thank you all for your answers, but I figured it out two hours before you posted the solution of the problem, But now I am interested to see the refactored version of the script. I am still learning PowerShell and I can see that my code is hideous. I would like to improve my self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commenten, the `if($null -eq $LogSeparator)` test will never succeed, because if not given, the parameter `$LogSeparator` will be an **empty string**, not `$null`.

The function you have would work if you change that to `if(!$LogSeparator)` or `if([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($LogSeparator))`

The function could be simplified by using a parameter that validates to a certain set of possible values. Extra advantage is that you get autocompletion in the editor aswell so you don't have to worry about sending a parameter value with a typo.

Something like this perhaps:

```
function Write-Log {
    param (
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $false)]
        [ValidateSet('Success', 'Fail', 'Partial', 'None')]
        [String]$OperationResult = 'None',

        [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = $false)]
        [String]$Message
    )

    $timestamp = Get-Date -Format "yyyy.MM.dd. HH:mm:ss:fff"
    $logEntry = $timestamp + " - " + $Message
    switch ($OperationResult) {
        'Success'  { $fg = 'Green'; $bg = 'Black'; break }
        'Fail'     { $fg = 'Red'; $bg = 'Black'; break }
        'Partial'  { $fg = 'Blue'; $bg = 'Black'; break }  # Cyan would be easier to read I think
        default    { $logEntry = $Message
                     $fg = 'Yellow'; $bg = 'Black' }
    }
    Write-Host $logEntry -ForegroundColor $fg -BackgroundColor $bg
    Add-content -Path $configuration.LogFile -Value $logEntry
    Add-content -Path $configuration.ReportFile -Value $logEntry
}
```

Testing:

```
Write-Log -Message $configuration.LogTitle
Write-Log -Message $configuration.LogSeparator

$message = "Successfully checked file - ready for transfer."
Write-Log -OperationResult Success -Message $message

$message = "Script stopped - MISSING FILE ERROR"
Write-Log -OperationResult Fail -Message $message

$message = "Script did not complete"
Write-Log -OperationResult Partial -Message $message

Write-Log -Message $configuration.LogSeparator
```

Result in console:

```
***********************************************  Remote Computer File Transfer PowerShell Script Log  ************************************************
******************************************************************************************************************************************************
2020.07.30. 21:34:53:959 - Successfully checked file - ready for transfer.
2020.07.30. 21:34:53:959 - Script stopped - MISSING FILE ERROR
2020.07.30. 21:34:53:959 - Script did not complete
******************************************************************************************************************************************************
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, but I figured it out two hours before you posted the solution of the problem, But now I am interested to see the refactored version of the script. I am still learning PowerShell and I can see that my code is hideous. I would like to improve my self.